# Django Custom Template Tag with Context Variable Argument

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have a custom template tag which shows a calendar.  I want to populate certain items on the calendar based on a dynamic value.

Here's the tag:

```
@register.inclusion_tag("website/_calendar.html")
def calendar_table(post):
     post=int(post)
     imp=IMP.objects.filter(post__pk=post)
     if imp:
         ...do stuff
```

In my template, it works fine when I pass a hard coded value, such as

```
    {% load inclusion_tags %}

    {% calendar_table "6" %}
```

However when I try something like {% calendar_table "{{post.id}}" %} , it raises a error a ValueError for the int() attempt.  How can I get around this?

Comment: In addition to Luke's good suggestion of using Variable.resolve, I also found another simple solution.  Setting context=True as an argument in the inclusion tag decorator adds the context of the current view as a dictionary.  You can then access the attr of the context object--context['variable']. It effectively looks like this: @register.inclusion_tag("template-to-include", takes_context=True)

Comment: The `takes_context=True` method ended up being the solutions for me. Note that you also need to have `context` as your first arg to the inclusion tag. I think you should make a separate answer for your solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want `{% calendar_table post.id %}`; the extra `{{` and `}}` are what are causing you the heartburn.

Note that, in your custom tag, you need to take the string (`"post.id"`) that gets passed and resolve it against the context using `Variable.resolve`. There's more information on that in the Django docs; in particular, look here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/#passing-template-variables-to-the-tag

Comment: Hey Luke, your suggestion worked great. I also found another solution to this problem that's pretty simple. See my comment above